# How to edit the exposure of an HDRI image using GraphicsMagick and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I have ImageMagick installed with support for HDRI images. Using bash, the following command can be used to save the image with a different number of 'stops' (where stops is a measure of exposure):

```
stops=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:pow(2,-1)]"`
convert input.exr \
    -colorspace RGB \
    -function polynomial "$stops,0" \
    -gamma 1 \
    -colorspace sRGB \
    output-minus-one-stop.jpg
```

In order to do this Node.js, some translation is needed:

```
var stops = Math.pow(2, -1);
gm('input.exr').colorspace('RGB')
    .out(`function polynomial "${stops},0"`)
    .gamma(1, 1, 1)
    .colorspace('sRGB')
    .write('output-minus-one-stop.jpg', function(err){});
```

However I get the error:

```
Command failed: convert: unable to open image `function polynomial "0.25,0"': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `25,0"' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501
```

The error is happening because of this line:

```
.out(`function polynomial "${stops},0"`)
```

What's the correct way to format the [out](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#custom-arguments%20%22Custom%20Arguments%20with%20GraphicsMagick%20and%20Node.js) command in this example?

Comment: I don't speak node, but I am fairly familiar with ImageMagick. The `gm` you have looks (to me) like GraphicsMagick rather than ImageMagick (the two are different) and I don't think GraphicsMagick has the `-function polynomial`. Can you move to IM rather than GM? I may be wrong on either count - and am happy to be corrected if anyone knows better.

Comment: It works with imagemagick. I didn't realize GM was missing the '-function polynomail' feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't speak node, but I am fairly familiar with ImageMagick.

The `gm` you have looks (to me) like **GraphicsMagick** rather than **ImageMagick** (the two are different) and I don't think **GraphicsMagick** has the `-function polynomial`.

Can you move to IM rather than GM? I may be wrong on either count - and am happy to be corrected if anyone knows better.